# Gráfico Raphael.js erro

Tags: javascript

Estou a criar um gráfico de linhas, utilizando a biblioteca [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/). Utilizei um exemplo, adicionei todos os script e tenho um erro no meu browser:

```
"Cannot read property 'linechart' of undefined".
```

O exemplo é muito simples:

```
<head>
    <title>gRaphaël Line Chart - a simple line chart example</title>
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphael/0.5.1/g.raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/graphael/0.5.1/g.line-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            // Creates canvas 640 × 480 at 10, 50
           var r = Raphael(10, 50, 640, 480);

            // Creates a simple line chart at 10, 10
            // width 300, height 220
            // x-values: [1,2,3,4,5], y-values: [10,20,15,35,30]
            r.g.linechart(10,10,300,220,[1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,15,35,30]);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>  
        <div id="holder"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O correto é:

```
r.linechart(10,10,300,220,[1,2,3,4,5],[10,20,15,35,30]);
```

O que o erro diz é que não existe a propriedade "g" em "r" e, logo, não existe a propriedade "linechart" nela.